# asp.net c#.net jquery / javascript how to enable or disable a requiredfieldvalidator using a checkbox

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, validation, checkbox

I am having an issue with trying to enable or disable a requiredfieldvalidator using a checkbox.  Obviously, when the checkbox is checked I want it to be enabled and unchecked to be disabled.  When the checkbox is checked it also opens up a FileUpload so obviously I would want that to register if there is not file chosen.  Here is some of my code.

HTML:

```
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkExecLAF" Text="Executed LAF" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="chkExecLAF_CheckedChanged" />
                </td>
                <td id="tblExecLAF">
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" CssClass="FileUpload1" />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvExecLAF" ControlToValidate="FileUpload1" ErrorMessage="*Required" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDatedLeaseAbstract" Text="Dated Lease Abstract" runat="server" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload2" runat="server" CssClass="FileUpload2" />
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Code Behind:

```
    protected void chkExecLAF_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            rfvExecLAF.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            rfvExecLAF.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

jquery:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.FileUpload1').attr('disabled', true);
        $('.rfvExecLAF').attr('disabled', true);
        $('.rfvExecLAF').hide();
        $('.FileUpload1').hide();
        $('#<%=chkExecLAF.ClientID %>').click(function () {

            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $('.FileUpload1').removeAttr('disabled');
                $('.rfvExecLAF').removeAttr('disabled');
                $('.rfvExecLAF').show();
                $('.FileUpload1').show();
            } else {
                $('.FileUpload1').attr('disabled', true);
                $('.rfvExecLAF').attr('disabled', true);
                $('.rfvExecLAF').hide();
                $('.FileUpload1').hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a breakpoint to your codebehind and see if that breakpoint is hit on CheckedChanged?

If it doesn't hit then you may want to add `AutoPostBack = 'true'` to your `chkExecLAF`

Comment: Ok, so I got that but for some reason it was destroying my jquery so now I am back at square one.  What I would like to do is just use jquery but it's not working at all for some reason.  Any ideas why my jquery script is not hiding or disabling the required field validator when checkbox is not checked?